# iOS Simulator has black Keyboard and Alerts in iOS7

Tags: xcode, user-interface, ios7, keyboard, ios-simulator

My App runs on iOS 6 and 7, on the devices it looks fine and on the simulator iOS6 it is fine but in iOS7 all alerts, keyboards and parts of table and collection views have elements that are completely black.  They are there if you clock on them.  It is hard to explain but you can see from the image.

I think it is do with the fact that I run a lot of things in the background and when I do any UI and force to the main thread (but this could be a red herring).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void)
{
    [self backgroundbits];
    ....
    ....
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
         [self updateProgressBar];
    });
    ....
    ....
    ....
});
```

Another options is that I have messed up the transparency and tint somehow.

It is just strange it ONLY does it on the iOS 7 simulator.

[image: Example of keyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this before. I just resorted the simulator (iOS Simulator > Restore Content and Settings), cleaned my Xcode Project, and quit and reopened Xcode. This solved the problem for me!

Comment: I did fix it and thought i put a not back up.  I can not remember if it was exactly this but it was a along the lines of cleaning up the Simulator. Thanks.